# Compare two files with using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, scripting

I have 2 files.

File 1 contains :-

```
emcas_biaas_dev=-628
emcas_brs_ba=-32
emcas_cc_analytics=246
emcas_edservices_bi=312
emcas_edservices_dev=-159
emcas_engr_usd=1519
emcas_engr_xio=-67
emcas_fin_bi=9
```

and File 2 contains :-

```
emcas_bdl_migrate=2
emcas_biaas_dev=63
emcas_brs_ba=430
emcas_cc_analytics=2231
emcas_clm_reporting=16
emcas_collab_xsat=6241
emcas_cpsd_cee=11
emcas_cpsd_hcp=0
emcas_e2ep_ba=187
emcas_edservices_bi=955
emcas_edservices_dev=374
emcas_elms_analytics=0
emcas_engr_clm=3
emcas_engr_scaleio=0
emcas_engr_usd=2669
emcas_engr_xio=340
emcas_fin_bi=333
emcas_fin_drr=5528
```

I want the desired output in a separate file as :-

```
emcas_biaas_dev=-628=63
emcas_brs_ba=-32=430
emcas_cc_analytics=246=2231
emcas_edservices_bi=312=955
emcas_edservices_dev=-159=374
emcas_engr_usd=1519=2669
emcas_engr_xio=-67=340
emcas_fin_bi=9=333
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task, a simpler tool than `awk` is `join`:

```
join -t '=' -1 1 -2 1 file1.txt file2.txt
```

## Explanation

See `man join` for more information, but:

- `-t '='`: use `=` as delimiter
- `-1 1 -2 1`: join on field 1 of file 1, and field 1 of file 2
- `file1.txt file2.txt`: join these two files.

Comment: It works well..!!

Answer (score 2):

I take it you want to output only fields whose key appears in both files, with both values. As mentioned in [Sparhawk’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465040/86440), the right tool for this is `join`. With AWK, the following works:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    OFS = FS = "="
}

FNR == NR {
    values[$1] = $2
}

FNR < NR {
    if (values[$1]) {
        print $1, values[$1], $2
    }
}
```

This starts by setting the input and output field separators to “=”, then parses the first file (`FNR == NR`), storing all its values in the `values` associative array, then it parses any following file (`FNR < NR`), and for each line, if a value was seen in the first file, outputs the key, the stored value, and the value in the current file.